# HttpClient and windows phone 8 portable

Tags: windows-phone-8, portable-class-library, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient, xamarin.forms

I'm having a very strange problem. I trying to do a WP8.0 application that uses a portable library. In this portable library, I'm using restsharp portable and everything was fine until instead of POSTs I started to do GETs. Going deeper, I found that the problem is in HttpClient, so I did a simple code just with HttpClient and found that using the same code in the following scenarios the results vary:
* in WP8+portable GET doesn't work, the call doesn't return but POST works fine
* in WP81 OK

I'm doing GET's to www.google.com and the POSTs to my own server. I am using the WP8.1 emulator for the tests.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please clarify your question?
Can you also post here some code examples that might help?

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

The code I was using to test was this:

```
  using (var client = new HttpClient())
  {
       client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://www.google.es/");
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
       HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("").Result;
       if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
       {
         text = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
       }
  }
```

The problem is using Result in GetAsync. I don't know why but it worked fine if I changed to 
await client.GetAsync("");

In my app, I have the code with await BUT the top level method wasn't async and I use .Result. The solution is not to use .Result when calling an async method (I don't know if it applies to every method or just HttpClient methods). The POST worked fine because they are in async methods.

Comment: Using .Result blocks the UI thread, and so therefore if there are any attempts to use the UI thread in the handling of the HTTP response you will get a deadlock.  Also, try not to create a new HttpClient on every request, treat it like a service and tear it down when you no longer need to make Http requests.